# Options for open source front end for C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am looking for options for an open source C++ compiler front-end (source parser/analyzer) that I could customize for my requirements. I do not need the back end implementation, just that it would help to find a fast and relatively bug free C++ front end that supports most standard features. Any suggestions?

[I did google, clang seems to be an option but i'd much prefer peer feedback before i begin with it.]

Arpan

Comment: @Carl, I am told that gcc front end code would be way too complex to understand and begin working on within a reasonable time span. Hence the search.

Comment: What do you mean by a "front end"?

Comment: Please list your actual requirements, might help people give more suggestions. The only two relatively mature open source C++ compiler front ends I know of are gcc and clang. C++ itself is quite complex, if you want something simpler I suggest C, perhaps the SDCC compiler which is fairly simplistic might help.

Comment: Code that'd help create the abstract syntax tree.

Comment: I don't see why any other front end would be significantly less complicated.

Comment: @Arpan There is no requirement that a compiler produce an AST. If you need one, you might look at ANTLR at http://www.antlr.org which seems to have  a c++ grammar available.

Comment: @Carl, according to http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/, gcc is "not the best documented code in the world, and the various stages of parsing (lexical, syntactic and semantic analysis) are fairly tangled together. It's also written in C, which is not the best language for a large, complicated program."

Comment: @Neil I don't think I ever mentioned that a compiler must produce an AST. It so happens that I am just looking for one that I can learn quickly and like Josh has mentioned probably CINT and ROSE are interesting options to look at.

Comment: Do you want an IDE? See http://codeblocks.org for one

Comment: Thanks Iulian for the suggestion -- I will checkout codeblocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang and GCC are the two main options.  GCC is very complicated (or so I've heard), and Clang is very promising but is immature.

[GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) uses GCC's frontend to spit out an XML description of the source.  GCC-XML's output is not a full abstract source tree (it doesn't contain function bodies), but it would be a lot easier to work with than GCC itself.  (The latest release on the GCC-XML page is horribly out of date; if you don't want to mess around with tracking its CVS yourself, you might try downloading a tarball from, e.g., [Debian's gccxml page](http://packages.debian.org/sid/gccxml).)

Depending on your exact requirements, other options might work:

- [CINT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) is a C / C++ interpreter.  I'm told that it's not very strict in its adherence to C++ standards.
- [ROSE](http://rosecompiler.org/) can take C and C++ source and lets you do a variety of transformations on it.  The C and C++ front-end of ROSE is licensed from EDG, so it's not open source, but it is freely redistributable.
- Projects such as [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) and [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) include their own limited C++ parsers.  Although these are only intended for extracting documentation and generating interfaces, respectively, they may meet your needs.

**Edit:**  For further reading, see ["Parsing C++"](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/), by Andrew Birkett.

Comment: gcc-xml doesn't contain the function body.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [LLVM clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

For one of the refactoring efforts I've done, we used Elsa:

http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/sources/elsa/

with mixed results. Some parts of our code were too complicated or nonstandard for Elsa to deal with, and had to be preprocessed out for the refactoring.

You can use this with Oink:

http://danielwilkerson.com/oink/

if source analysis is what you're in the mood for.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The Digital Mars C++ compiler is not open source, but the source code is available for purchase (see http://www.digitalmars.com/shop.html) and you can customize it.

Answer (score 0):

CLang is probably the way to go these days for a comprehensive solution, but if you're looking for something standalone that you can understand then check out this project on github:

https://github.com/robertoraggi/cplusplus

Out of the box it comes with a little command line utility to dump the AST, symbols, and IR code.

This is the C++ front end used in [QTCreator](http://wiki.qt.io/Category:Tools::QtCreator).  It does a decent job parsing most modern C++ code and even though the cplusplus front end hasn't been updated for a while, QTCreator is very actively used and developed.  This code has quite a bit of mileage on it.